# C Variable Length Arrays storage duration

Tags: c, scope

On [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) site there is the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> - automatic storage duration. The storage is allocated when the block in which the object was declared is entered and deallocated when it is exited by any means (goto, return, reaching the end). One exception is the VLAs; their storage is allocated when the declaration is executed, not on block entry, and deallocated **when the declaration goes out of scope, not than when the block is exited (since C99)**. If the block is entered recursively, a new allocation is performed for every recursion level. All function parameters and non-static block-scope objects have this storage duration, as well as compound literals used at block scope.

What is the difference between a declaration going out of scope and a block being exited? Can you provide an example?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array See the section about variable-length arrays. It has a nice example.

Comment: @DeiDei I read that example and it doesn't specify exactly the difference between the two. I can only think that there is a special instruction right at the end of the block which is responsible for de-allocating the memory for the VLA. So if the block is exited with a `return` or `goto`, the memory is not de-allocated. Is this correct?

Comment: Basically it is a note for all the spaghetti coders. If you write sane code, you don't need to care about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the N1570 draft of the C11 specification §6.2.4/7

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its
>   lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of
>   the program leaves the scope of the declaration.

The specification then adds this helpful note:

> Leaving the innermost block containing the declaration, or jumping to
>   a point in that block or an embedded block prior to the declaration,
>   leaves the scope of the declaration.

So the VLA is de-allocated when the execution goes outside the scope of the VLA, which includes the section in the same block before the declaration of the VLA.

Jumping to a point prior to the declaration can be done with a `goto` statement. For example:

```
int n = 0;
while (n < 5)
{
top:
    n++;
    char array[n];
    if (n < 2)
        goto top;
}
```

In this code, the block is not exited when the `goto` is executed. However, the value of `n` changes, so a new `array` needs to be allocated. That's the horribly convoluted situation that the specification is trying to support.

Comment: Thank you. So the VLA is de-allocated when the execution goes outside the scope of the VLA, which includes the section in the same block before the declaration of the VLA.

Comment: @user42768 Yes, that's a great way to put it. Is it alright if I copy that comment into the answer?

Comment: user3386109 Of course, anything to make future readers understand this better.

Comment: suppose formal definition uses different words, real machine code diferent. Belive frame on the stack is decremented after function return (i.e. variables from internal block have not sense in high level language, but stack is not midified)

Comment: On the contrary, @JacekCz, it is highly likely that stack space is not reserved for a VLA until a point in the machine code corresponding to its declaration, because its size can depend on code preceding that declaration in the same block.  It is also plausible that that space really is deallocated when the VLA goes out of scope, because it might have a different size at its reallocation.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the difference between a declaration going out of scope and a block being exited? Can you provide an example?

The scope of a block-scope identifier starts at its declaration and extends to the end of the innermost enclosing block.  This applies to identifiers of every kind, not just those of VLAs.  It is possible for control to leave the scope of an identifier without exiting the innermost block containing it by transferring to a point preceding the identifier's declaration.  The most obvious way to accomplish that would be via a `goto` statement:

```
int f(int n) {
    // i is allocated here, _before_ the beginning of its scope
    label: // if control returns here via the goto below, vla is _de_allocated
           // at this point
    printf("n is %d", n);

    int vla[n]; // vla is (re)allocated here, at the beginning of its scope
    int i;
    int sum;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vla[i] = rand();
        sum += vla[i];
    }

    if (sum < SOME_THRESHOLD) goto label; 

    return sum;  // vla and i are both deallocated when control exits the block
}
```

The difference in when a VLA is deallocated vs. when an ordinary automatic object is deallocated mirrors the difference between when the two types of objects are allocated.  VLA's live only within the scope of their identifiers.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer, but I can only accept one, and @user3386109's answer was first.